# DatePicker - On Friday after 3pm, Monday disable

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need help to add rules for datePicker.

For current rules, any day (exclude weekends) after 3pm the following day will disable as per sample codes below. Also on current day disable too.

But my client want to add another rule, on every Friday after 3pm, instead disable on next day which already disabled they want it on Monday instead.

I need help as per screenshot below. 1st May is on Friday, and on coming Monday should disable.

[image]

```js
 //Date Picker
  var dateToday = new Date().getHours();
  $(function() {
    $( "#ContactDate" ).datepicker({
      //minDate: dateToday,
      minDate: dateToday >= 15 ? 2 : 1,
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
      maxDate: '+1m'
    });
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<input type="text" class="form-control w-input" placeholder="Select date" id="ContactDate">

<script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.220afd743d.js?site=5de87425133808841c6e3b3e" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where you check `dateToday`[sic: should be `timeToday`] also check dayOfWeek and add a corresponding offset to your minDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you check the hour (your variable `dateToday`) you can also check dayOfWeek and add a corresponding offset to your minDate.

Days of the week start at 0 = Sunday, so Friday == 5.

Below is updated code including passing in a date so that it can easily be demonstrated given different date/time combinations:

```js
//Date Picker

function addDatePicker(selector, forDate) {

  var hours = forDate.getHours();
  var dow = forDate.getDay();
  var minDate = forDate.setDate(forDate.getDate() + (hours >= 15 ? 2 : 1) + (dow == 5 ? 2 : 0));

  $(selector).datepicker({
    minDate: forDate,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    maxDate: '+1m'
  });
}

addDatePicker("#ContactDateToday", new Date());
addDatePicker("#ContactDateWedAM", new Date(2020, 3, 29, 10));
addDatePicker("#ContactDateWedPM", new Date(2020, 3, 29, 18));
addDatePicker("#ContactDateFriAM", new Date(2020, 4, 1, 10));
addDatePicker("#ContactDateFriPM", new Date(2020, 4, 1, 18));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> Today/Now:
<input type="text" class="form-control w-input" placeholder="Select date" id="ContactDateToday">
<hr/> Wed before 3:
<input type="text" class="form-control w-input" placeholder="Select date" id="ContactDateWedAM">
<hr/> Wed after 3:
<input type="text" class="form-control w-input" placeholder="Select date" id="ContactDateWedPM">
<hr/> Fri before 3:
<input type="text" class="form-control w-input" placeholder="Select date" id="ContactDateFriAM">
<hr/> Fri after 3:
<input type="text" class="form-control w-input" placeholder="Select date" id="ContactDateFriPM">
```

Comment: Thank you so much freedom-m, you really save my workload this week.